# Advanced OptiX denoiser settings missing in 2.91

Tags: denoise

Where are the advanced OptiX denoiser settings like radius, strength, feature strength, etc. in 2.91? They were in the view layer settings in 2.83, but I can't find them any more.

[image: 2.91]

[image: 2.83]

Comment: You have to select one of the denoising options from the Render Properties tab (pick a denoiser and check the box), Once you've done this, the denoise settings will appear in the bottom of the View Layers tab.

Comment: I did have the denoiser selected, but if you pick OptiX or OpenImageDenoise you only get an option of input passes without further options to tweak, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. These settings are only for the NLM denoiser, not for OptiX (nor OpenImageDenoise). I somehow misread the docs at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html.